# Strange integral sum. Where did I go wrong?

Tags: integration, functions, infinitesimals

Let $f(x)=x^2$. $df(x)=2xdx$

For $x=0$: $f(0+dx)-f(0)=0$. Thus $f(dx)=0$.

I want to find area under the curve $f(x)=x^2$ from $0$ to $b$: $\int x^2dx = f(0)dx + f(0+dx)dx + f(0+2dx)dx + ... + f(0+(n-1)dx)dx$ where $dx=b/n$, $n=\infty$.

But if $f(0+dx) = 0$ as I mentioned above, then I get wrong sum: $f(0)dx + f(0+dx)dx + ... = 0dx + 0dx + ...$

What is wrong with my reasoning?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how you get "$f(0 + dx) - f(0) = 0$"?

Comment: In line 2 you seem to prove that if $f$ has zero derivative at a point $x$ then $f$ is identically $0$. The sum of infinitely many infinitely small terms is not something that is well-defined, either.

Comment: @VTand $f(x+dx) = f(x) + f'(x)dx$ for $x=0$ : $f(0+dx) - f(0) = 0$

Comment: @MichalAdamaszek Ok. I read in one book that If we have point $B(dx,dx^2)$ on the graph of the function $f(x)=x^2$ then point B is upon the X axis - $B(dx,0)$. How is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have made it wrong. When dealing with infinitesimals we have to he careful.

$f(x+dx)-f(x)=(x+dx)²-x²=2xdx+dx²$
For $x=0$ it's $dx²$, not $0$.

Now, when dealing with integration, the result of integration, let $dx=\frac{b}{\omega}$ for some arbitrary infinite natural numbers $\omega$. Then the integration, for every infenitesimal $\varepsilon$ (s.t
$-dx<\varepsilon<dx$) , will be equal to standard part (real number infinitely close to that) of:

$\sum_{i=0}^\omega f(0+\varepsilon+i dx)dx$

Which is equal to:

$dx\sum_{i=0}^\omega \varepsilon²+2\varepsilon dx+i²dx²=dx( \varepsilon²\omega+2\varepsilon dx\sum_{i=0}^\omega i +dx²\sum_{i=0}^\omega i²)=dx(\varepsilon²\omega+2\varepsilon dx\frac{(\omega+1)\omega}{2}+dx²\frac{\omega(\omega+1)(2\omega+1)}{6})=(\text{substituting $dx=\frac{b}{\omega}$})=b\varepsilon²+2b²\varepsilon\frac{(1+\frac{1}{\omega})}{2}+b³\frac{(1+\frac{1}{\omega})(2+\frac{1}{\omega})}{6}\approx 0+0+b³\frac{(1+0)\cdot (2+0)}{6}=\frac{b³}{3}$